# Can't Get GPS Current Location's Latitude and Longitude Android

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to get Current Location using either `GPS` or `Network Provider`. My device's `GPS` is enabled but I'm not getting `Latitude` and `Longitude`.

**GpsTracker.java:**

```
public class GpsTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

        private final Context mContext;
        // flag for GPS Status
        boolean isGPSEnabled = false; 
        // flag for network status
        boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
        boolean canGetLocation = false; 
        Location location;
        public double latitude;
        public double longitude;

        // The minimum distance to change updates in metters
        private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 
         // metters

         // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
         private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

                    // Declaring a Location Manager
                    protected LocationManager locationManager;

                    public GpsTracker(Context context) {
                        this.mContext = context;
                        getLocation();
                    }

                    public Location getLocation() {
                        try {
                            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                             // getting GPS status
                            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); 

                            // getting network status
                            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


                                // if Network Provider Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                                    if (location == null) {
                                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);


                                        if (locationManager != null) {
                                            location = locationManager
                                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                                            updateGPSCoordinates();
                                        }
                                    }   
                                }

                                 // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                                    if (location == null) {
                                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                                        if (locationManager != null) {
                                            location = locationManager
                                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                            if (location != null) {
                                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } 
                                }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e("Error : Location",
                                    "Impossible to connect to LocationManager", e); 
                        }

                        return location;
                    }

                    public void updateGPSCoordinates() {
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        } 
                    }

                    public double getLatitude() {
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        }

                        return latitude;
                    }

                    public double getLongitude() { 
                        if (location != null) {
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }

                        return longitude;
                    }
                }
```

Service.Java

```
    public class WifiScaningService extends IntentService {

        GpsTracker gpsTracker;
        double latitude;
            double longitude;
        public WifiScaningService() {
                super("WifiScaningService"); 

            }

            @Override 
            public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {    
                // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate() {
                Log.e("service call","service call");
            }  


            @Override
            protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

            } 
            @Override


            public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) { 
                    Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);

                    gpsTracker = new GpsTracker(this); 
                    String stringLatitude = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.latitude);
                    latitude = Double.parseDouble(stringLatitude);
                    Log.e("Latitude",stringLatitude);
                    String stringLongitude = String.valueOf(gpsTracker.longitude);
                    longitude = Double.parseDouble(stringLongitude);
                    Log.e("Longitude",stringLongitude); 

                return START_STICKY;
            }
    }
```

I have included necessary permissions in AndroidManifest.xml file. Required to show current location.

```
<uses-permission
  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
        uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Does your code compile? I cannot see the onLocationChanged() method which your GpsTracker needs to implement since it implements the LocationListener interface.

Comment: Yes, No issue in Compiling and onLocationChanged() is removed in this code

Comment: Since this is the method which gets called if a new position is available you should post it. getLastKnownLocation might give you a very old location and it might be null, which may possibly is the reason why you get 0 as result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved by exchanging position of both methods.

First app trying to get location using `GPS` if `GPS` is not enabled then using network provider method.

```
public class GpsTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS Status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
boolean canGetLocation = false;
Location location;
public double latitude;
public double longitude;

// The minimum distance to change updates in metters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10
// metters

// The minimum time beetwen updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GpsTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
        if (isGPSEnabled) {
            if (location == null) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if Network Provider Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);


                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        updateGPSCoordinates();
                    }
                }
            }


        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Error : Location",
                "Impossible to connect to LocationManager", e);
    }

    return location;
}

public void updateGPSCoordinates() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
}

public double getLatitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    return longitude;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

MainActivity:

```
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Location;
import com.example.havadurumumenu.MyLocationManager.LocationHandler;

public class MainActivityextends Activity implements LocationHandler{

    public MyLocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentLocation();              
            }
        });
    }

    public void currentLocation(){

        locationManager = new MyLocationManager();
        locationManager.setHandler(this);

        boolean isBegin = locationManager.checkProvidersAndStart(getApplicationContext());
        if(isBegin){
            //if at least one of the location providers are on it comes into this part.
        }else{
            //if none of the location providers are on it comes into this part.
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void locationFound(Location location) {
        Log.d("LocationFound", ""+location);

        //you can reach your Location here
        //double latitude = location.getLatitude(); 
        //double longtitude = location.getLongitude();

        locationManager.removeUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void locationTimeOut() {
        locationManager.removeUpdates();

         //you can set a timeout in MyLocationManager class

        txt.setText("Unable to locate. Check your phone's location settings");
    }
```

MyLocationManager:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;

/*---------- Listener class to get coordinates ------------- */
public class MyLocationManager implements LocationListener {

    public LocationManager locationManager;
    public LocationHandler handler;
    private boolean isLocationFound = false;

    public MyLocationManager() {}

    public LocationHandler getHandler() {
        return handler;
    }

    public void setHandler(LocationHandler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }
    @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
    public boolean checkProvidersAndStart(Context context){
        boolean isBegin = false;

        Handler stopHandler = new Handler(){
            public void handleMessage(Message msg){
                if (!isLocationFound) {
                        handler.locationTimeOut();
                }
            }
        };
        stopHandler.sendMessageDelayed(new Message(), 15000);

        locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 1000, this);
            isBegin = true;
        }
        if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 1000, this);
            isBegin = true;
        }
        return isBegin;     
    }

    public void removeUpdates(){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }
    /**
     * To get city name from coordinates
     * @param location is the Location object
     * @return city name
     */
    public String findCity(Location location){
        /*------- To get city name from coordinates -------- */
        String cityName = null;
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(AppController.getInstance(), Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses;
        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
            cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cityName;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        isLocationFound = true;
        handler.locationFound(loc);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public interface LocationHandler{
        public void locationFound(Location location);
        public void locationTimeOut();
    }
}
```

Also add all the permissions below in your Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```